# Passing double arrays between functions in asm.js

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten, asm.js

I have a C function compiled into asm.js with the following parameters:

```
void myfunc(double v1[], double v2[], int v_size, double c)
```

It takes in an array (`v1`), applies a transformation, then fills another array of the same size (`v2`) with the output.

I compile it, and then run the following JS code:

```
v1 = new Array(1.0, 1.5, 2.0);
v2 = Module._malloc(8 * v1.length);

Module.ccall("myfunc", null, ["array", "number", "number", "number"], [v1, v2, v1.length, 2]);
```

However when I run `getValue(v2, "double")` I get 1.297703e-318 (which is wrong), and when I run `getValue(v2 + 8, "double")` or `getValue(v2 + 16, "double")` it returns 0 (which is also wrong).

I've reduced the C function to just console log out the contents of `v1` and it prints out garbage data as well, so at least there is an issue with reading a double array passed in. The more specific questions are:

1. How do I correctly pass in a double array into an asm.js function?
2. How do I correctly return a double array from an asm.js function?

Comment: Shouldn't the ["array", "number", "number", "number"] be ["array", "array", "number", "number"] ?

Comment: @threadp: I was told on the asm.js IRC channel that since v2 is not a Javascript array, I shouldn't use "array" to pass it, to use "number" instead.

Comment: @Lucas, in that case, why isn't it ["number", "number", "number", "number"]?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, v1 is a native JS array. It gets converted to a "pointer" within the [ccall function](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/07b87426f898d6e9c677db291d9088c839197291/src/preamble.js#L137)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a bit late to this, but for what it's worth...

When working with passing numeric types between JS and the Emscripten run-time I've found I've had to work with `Uint8Array` type typed arrays, changing the view from another type if necessary. Something like this:

```
myfunc = Module.cwrap('myfunc', null, ['array']);
var v1 = new Float64Array([2.3, 4.2, 6.8, 8.9]);
var uarray = new Uint8Array(v1.buffer); // change the view to Uint8
                                        // before passing
myfunc(uarray);
```

with a C function like this:

```
void mfunc(const double *v1)
{
   printf("%f %f %f %f\n", v1[0], v1[1], v1[2], v1[3]);
}
```

should see the values printed out. Note, if you try writing to the memory pointed to by v1 (obviously removing the `const` first) and accessing `v1` in the JavaScript, you'll notice that your changes  are ignored, as `ccall` and `cwrap` use the stack for passing the array.

To alter an array on the C side, you need to use `Module._malloc` to allocate some memory in the Emscripten run-time, this gives you a 'pointer' (treated as a number by JavaScript and referred to as a number in `cwrap`) which you can read and write from. You can use `Module.getValue` to 'dereference' the pointer:

```
myfunc = Module.cwrap('myfunc', null, ['array', 'number']);
var v1 = new Float64Array([2.3, 4.2, 6.8, 8.9]);
var uarray = new UintArray(v1.buffer);

var ptr = Module._malloc(v1.byteLength);
myfunc(uarray, ptr);

for (var i=0; i<v1.length; i++)
{
   console.log(Module.getValue(ptr+i*v1.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 'double'));
}
```

and a C function like this:

```
void mfunc(const double *v1, double *v2)
{
   printf("%f %f %f %f\n", v1[0], v1[1], v1[2], v1[3]);

   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
       v2[i] = 2 * v1[i];
   }
}
```

Should see a list of the values of v1 being doubled and printed on the browser JS console.

Obviously, you could also pass the array into `myfunc` using a similar method, but you have to clean up any `_malloc`ed data, so I tend to avoid doing that for values I want don't want to alter.