# emscripten read javascript arrayBuffer in C

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten

This code is incorrect but it tells what I am trying to do

```
char* p = EM_ASM(
    var a = new ArrayBuffer(8);
    return a;
);
```

What is the correct way of getting a C pointer of that javascript arrayBuffer?
I only want to read the arrayBuffer not write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no direct way of returning an array from some inline JavaScript (although there is a way of returning read-only arrays from JavaScript wrapped C functions, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060714/passing-double-arrays-between-functions-in-asm-js/38171198#38171198)). What you can do instead is malloc space for the array in a C function, pass the address to the inline Emscripten, and use the Emscripten JavaScript function `writeArrayToMemory` to copy your JavaScript array into the `malloc`ed memory. Something like this...

```
char *a = malloc(4);

EM_ASM_INT({
    var v1 = new Uint8Array([2,4,6,8]);

    writeArrayToMemory(v1, $0)
    }, a);

printf("the array is [%d, %d, %d, %d]\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
```