# Web assembly : sending data from js to argv argument of C++ main function

Tags: javascript, c++, program-entry-point, argv, webassembly

I want to send an array of string to my "main" C++ function.
I have tried this:

```
   this.module = buildModule(args).then((res) => {
     const main = res.cwrap('main', 'number', ['number', 'array'])

    // create a pointer using the 'Glue' method and the String value
    const ptr1 = res.allocate(wasmBuild.intArrayFromString('test'), 'i8', 0)
    main(2, [ptr1])
  }
```

I receive the int (2) but the "argv" arguments print only garbage on the other size...
What am I doing wrong? 
Also, has anyone be able to use the 'array' argument?
According to the doc:

> The [parameter] types are (...) “array” (for 
>   a JavaScript array or typed array that corresponds to a C array; for 
>   typed arrays, it must be a Uint8Array or Int8Array).

Comment: `array` for `cwrap` means `Uint8Array` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060714/passing-double-arrays-between-functions-in-asm-js/38171198#38171198